# WCF service call after iisreset

Tags: wcf

After an iisreset, when i make a call to my WCF service, it takes long time for the first time alone. can anyone help to find the reasons. I have used fiddler to find the time taken for the service call. it was almost 55 to 65 seconds for the first time after the iisreset. consequitive calls are made in less then  15 to 20 seconds.

Comment: Depends on your app, you're probably seeing some startup costs.

Answer (score 1):

it is a normal behavior. Due to internal tasks (loading framework, compiling some assemblies, validating configuration, ...) the first call is always taking nearly 15 seconds. All the others calls will be faster.
If you want to have a faster "fist-call", you have to use AppFabric AutoStart feture.

Comment: Thanks for the response Cybermaxs, but my first call is taking nearly a minute. Would i need to check on anything else, can u provide me with somelink on what all internal tasks  happening.

Comment: Sorry but i cannot : it's internal in IIS/WCF and some parts are native (not in Dotnet). You could use a custom profiler to monitor your startup (like a static initializer) but not sure you will find something.